# Can we partition an open set by finitely many open subsets?

Tags: general-topology

If we have open set, e.g. $(0, 1)$ or an open disc, is it possible to partition the it by finitely many open subsets?

Obviously we ignore the trivial case which is the subset itself.

Comment: The examples you give are not only open, they are connected. The latter property is what is relevant to your question.

Comment: I would say yes- take out the middle chunk, say $(\frac14, \frac34)$?

Comment: @ColmBhandal: The complement is not open.

Comment: Of course, that would break the connectivity, but I think it would still be open.

Comment: Oh yes silly mistake.

Comment: Take a point $x \in U$ in the open set, take a small ball $B$ around $x$ contained in $U$. Take a smaller ball contained in $B$ call that $V$ take $\overline{V}^{C} \cup B$. If this is not right then please add more explanation to your question.

Comment: @baharampuri: That need not be a partition as $\overline{V}^c$ and $B$ may not be disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be a topological space. We say $X$ is *disconnected* if there are disjoint open non-empty subsets $A, B \subset X$ such that $X = A\cup B$. If $U$ is not disconnected, we say that it is connected.

Suppose $X$ is an open set which can be partitioned into finitely many proper open subsets. Let $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^nU_i$ where the $U_i$ are disjoint open non-empty sets (and therefore proper subsets of $X$). Setting $A = U_1$ and $B = \bigcup_{i=2}^nU_i$, we see that $X = A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint open non-empty subsets of $X$. Therefore, any such $X$ must be disconnected. It is worth noting that we don't need to assume the partition is finite. That is, we have the following stronger statement:

> If $X$ can be partitioned by proper open subsets, then $X$ is disconnected.

As $(0, 1)$ and the open disc $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 < r\}$ are connected, the above result shows that they cannot be partitioned into finitely many proper open sets.

Any disconnected space $X$ can be partitioned into its connected components $\{C_i \mid i \in I\}$ which are closed. If $X$ has finitely many connected components (i.e. $I$ is finite), then the connected components are also open. Then the union $X = \bigcup_{i\in I} C_i$ provides a partition of $X$ into finitely many proper open subsets. Note, the assumption on the number of connected components is necessary as the connected components of a disconnected space can need not be open. For example, the connected components of $\mathbb{Q}$ are singletons which are closed but not open.